# Change global "editable" callback value in FullCalendar based on user role

Tags: coldfusion, fullcalendar

I am using the [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) jQuery plugin along with ColdFusion and MySQL. I have two user levels, 'Admin' and 'Read-Only'. I would like the 'Read-Only' users to only be able to view events on the calendar and not make any changes, while the 'Admin' role has full editing capabilities. I was hoping to do this by adding a function to the FullCalendar `editable` option that would be set to `true` if the user's role is an Admin and `false` if the user role Read-Only.

The variable `userRole` is set in the page header based on a ColdFusion session variable. I verified that `userRole` does contain the correct string when called in the javascript.

What I tried:

```
$("#calendar").fullCalendar({
    // other options and callbacks
    // ....

    editable: function(){
        if (userRole == 'Read-Only') {
            return false //events can not be modified
        }
        else if (userRole == 'Admin') {         
            return true  //events can be modified
        }
    },
    // other callbacks
    // ...
});
```

When I step through the code with Firebug, the whole function for the `editable` option is skipped and events are editable for both user types.

Is there a flaw in my jQuery function (I'm new to programming in jQuery)? Does the FullCalendar `editable` option not allow a function?

I can get around this by doing a user role check for each FullCalendar callback (e.g. eventDrop, eventResize, select, and eventClick)

```
select: function(start, end, allDay) {
        // check if user is Admin, if not, unselect and return
        if (userRole != 'Admin') {
            alert("You do not have the permissions to edit events.");
            $("#calendar").fullCalendar( 'unselect' );
            return
        }

        // proceed if user is Admin
        // ...
}
```

and only proceed if the user role is 'Admin', but I was hoping to be able to set the role more globally.

Ideas?

Comment: where are you setting the userRole value in your JS?

Comment: It is being set in the `<head>` with `var userRole = '#SESSION.userType#';`

Comment: if you do `console.log(userRole);` what value is being outputted? Sounds like your Read-Only value may not be outputting how you think it should.

Comment: when logging in as a read-only user, `console.log(userRole);` shows `Read-Only` and when logging in as an admin it shows `Admin`

Comment: I also tested the `userRole` variable by adding an `alert(userRole);` as the first line in the `select: ...` callback, which worked fine and output the expected value.

Comment: What function is being skipped?  editable?  Does the FullCalendar plugin have such a function?

Comment: it looks like the callback `editable` is being skipped. Usually you just set the editable callback with `editable: true,` [editable callback](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_ui/editable/)

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how the empty jQuery function works, but I was hoping it would just return `true` or `false` when the `editable` callback was triggered?

Comment: Documentation says [editable](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_ui/editable/) is an option, not a callback...

Comment: You are right, MaxD - looks like I labeled it incorrectly, I should have said 'option' not 'callback' for `editable`. But for options, can you use an empty function to assign the value?

Comment: Don't think so; it is just evaluating as a function pointer==!false. Your second method is  better (w/o modyfing FC code), just checking the userRole in `select`, `eventDrop`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple ways you can solve this problem depending on your implementation of the calendar.

Since you are using ColdFusion to set a JavaScript variable already, can't you just simply do the following:

```
editable: <cfif session.userType eq 'Admin'>true<cfelse>false</cfif>
```

Alternatively, the way I control it is through the Event object. I usually set the Calendar to "editable: false" by default but then selectively allow the event objects to be editable on a per object basis.  I generate my events from ColdFusion through a webservice cfc returning JSON and let ColdFusion decide who gets to edit what and just use FullCalendar for display.

Comment: I will look into getting ColdFusion tags to work within Javascript - I couldn't get your above suggestion to work as written. Although, it looks like it may be easier to just leave things as I have it right now and check the user type individually for each callback.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention, i just call the file as javascript but its actually calling "calendar.js.cfm" e.g. <script type="text/javascript" src="calendar.js.cfm"></script>
:-)